# Do not show repository output attributes on the basis of runtime requirements

Tags: java, spring-boot

My code:

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class CatalogController {

@Autowired
CatalogService catalogService;
@Autowired
Helper<List<?>> helperList;

@GetMapping("/addresses/{streetCode}")
public ResponseEntity<?> listByStreetCode(
        @PathVariable("streetCode") String streetCode, @RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {

    String showDoor = map.get("do");

    return helperList.evaluateCorrectHttpResponse(
                a -> catalogService.listAddressesByStreetCode(streetCode, showDoor ));

}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class CatalogService {

@Autowired
VAddressesRepository vAddressesRepository;

public List<VAddresses> listAddressesByStreetCode(String streetCode, String showDoor ) {

    // The following repository output should contain every VAddresses attribute or every attribute but 'door', depending on the parameter 'showDoor '    

    return vAddressesRepository.findByStreetCode(Integer.valueOf(streetCode));
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vAddress", schema = "foo")
public class VAddresses {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    String geoid;

    String var1;
    // other variables
    String door;
    // getters and setters
}
```

So, is there a way to skim model attributes based on showDoor value? Bare in mind that I have to operate on the service layer, not on the controller one because it is standardized.

I tried this example https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria. But I've gotten errors stating

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class foo.models.VAddresses]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'showDoorFilter'; no FilterProvider configured (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])",
```

even though I defined showDoorFilter in the service layer before invoking Addresses repository.

Should you have examples on how to apply baeldung's code in this case or better suggestions on how to deal with this issue, feel free to write them.
Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**
I suggest that when you get the list of object from repository you can make a list of map, then for each object you can first convert it to a map then just remove the key corresponding to the object that need not be serialized from the corresponding map, it will done for all the object and return the list of map because as we know JsonFormat string is nothing but a combination of key and value pair so just by looking at json output It can't be easily differentiated whether it is an object or map in case like this.
Here you have to change the return type to List of Map

You can convert object to map using jackson ObjectMapper

below is the example

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
UserName obj = new UserName();
obj.setName("mss");
obj.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java","spring"));

Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

Output

```
{name=mss, skills=[java, spring]}
```

**Second Method**
if you think this is too much of a work
then you can first convert the list that you got from repository to jsonArray and then for each jsonObject in the jsonArray remove the corresponding key which matches with the name of the field which you want to be serialized

**Edit** : sorry, I didn't know that you can only iterate with the for each loop on instances of java.lang.Iterable. JSONArray is not one of them.
so we will use normal variable for loop with the help of length of JSONArray

```
@Service
public class CatalogService {

@Autowired
VAddressesRepository vAddressesRepository;

public JSONArray listAddressesByStreetCode(String streetCode, String showDoor ) {

    // The following repository output should contain every VAddresses attribute or every attribute but 'door', depending on the parameter 'showDoor '    

    List<VAddresses> lists = vAddressesRepository.findByStreetCode(Integer.valueOf(streetCode));
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(lists));

    int n = jsonArray.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
      jsonObject.remove(showDoor); // removing the key matching with the required field that is to be not serialized, key has to be in string format
      jsonArray.put(i , jsonObject);
      /* put the updated jsonObject in the index, even through Java is reference type so when you deleted the key
         from jsonObject it should be updated in jsonArray index i, but for surety */
    } 
    return jsonArray;
}
```

let me know it it works or not

Comment: I got inspiration from your first method. Unfortunately, the second one doesn't work. The iteration attempt on JSONArray generates the error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". Furthermore, .remove() wants an index to remove an entire element of the list, which is not wat I'm looking for. BTW thank you!

Comment: @LetiziaBrunetti  no problem, updated the answer for second method